# Waze inside a flutter application?

Tags: flutter, waze

My question is : "Is it possible to run WAZE app inside a Flutter Application ?"
I do not want to launch WAZE application outside my app
I would like to run WAZE app inside a container in my application to keep the user inside my app.
I do not want to run Waze in a navigator because to have real time navigation we need to run Waze / App and not Waze / web
Do you know if it is possible and how to do it ?
Thank's 1000 times :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Waze doesn't support embedding its client into another app, so I suspect this won't be possible with Flutter either. On [their developers page](https://developers.google.com/waze), you can see the permitted ways of integrating Waze.

The closest to what you seem to be asking seems to be the [Transport SDK](https://developers.google.com/waze/intro-transport), which gives you access to the ETA, next turn instruction and geodata of the route. The access to this SDK requires approval by Waze though, and I know that they're quite restrictive in this. So your luck may vary to get into this program.